# I attempted to enable the EPEL repo on my Fedora 22 machine and I broke it, now errors are thrown

Tags: fedora, epel

I made the attempt at enabling EPEL on my Fedora 22 machine by running

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm`

Then

`sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm`

And now when I run

`dnf repolist`

I get the following

```
[sinux1@horrible-host ~]$ sudo dnf repolist
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  1.8 MB/s | 9.0 MB     00:05    
Failed to open: /var/cache/dnf/epel-2b6dfc5904c26562/repodata/49c4e3bd54f19136521be9b254830c954369cc22ce1b661db502ebef13b0004c-updateinfo.xml.bz2.
[sinux1@horrible-host ~]$
```

I'm stuck and not sure what my next step is. How can I reverse what I did, and what would have been the proper way of enabling EPEL?
Thanks for any input

Comment: You could always `rpm --erase epel-release`, or remove the file from `/etc/yum.repos.d`

Comment: Stackoverflow is generally for programming related questions.  You are likely to get a better ansewr to this question on http://serverfault.com (a stackoverflow.com sister site)

Comment: @Rup thank you... and next time I'll post this in the correct place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what appears to have worked for me.

Remove the epel repo

rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*

then try install epel via dnf

dnf clean all
dnf install epel-release

Answer (score 1):

I did the same as Sinux Tine and ended up in some sort of deadlock.

First try to do like Rup says.

If *everything* fails, try the following as a last resort. It worked for me.

```
> su
> cd /var/cache/dnf/epel-2b6dfc5904c26562/repodata
> mkdir throwaway
> mv 49c4e3bd54f19136521be9b254830c954369cc22ce1b661db502ebef13b0004c-updateinfo.xml.bz2 throwaway
```

That effectively deletes the file which dnf says it cannot open.

When and if the problem is solved, you can delete the throwaway directory and its contents.

Comment: @klauss I did what Rup said and it worked for me, but I will definitely keep your recommendation in my pocket. I'm always tinkering, always breaking stuff :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Current libsolv version does not have bz2 compression.
Solution: enable bunzip2 compression in libsolv, Basically 'yum update libsolv', then reinstall epel-release.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer for `Centos 7`, I followed the next steps:

Download the `libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7` wich was [patched](https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/ngompa/dnf-el7/epel-7-x86_64/00147945-libsolv/libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm)

Install it 
`sudo rpm -ivh libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

If we get a conflict with the previous version

```
warning: libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1b6f9f55: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /usr/lib64/libsolv.so.0 from install of libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libsolv-0.6.11-1.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/libsolvext.so.0 from install of libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libsolv-0.6.11-1.el7.x86_64
```

We proceed to remove the previous version

`sudo yum erase libsolv-0.6.11-1.el7.x86_64`

and install the patched libsolv package

`sudo rpm -ivh libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

We need to reinstall the `dnf` package manager, because it was removed after to remove the libsolv so we install with the following command.

`sudo yum install dnf`

We validate it using `sudo dnf repolist` now it, give us the right output.

```
Using metadata from Mon Jun 13 10:53:11 2016
repo id        repo name                   status
base           CentOS-7 - Base             9,007
```